# Set tkinter icon on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, icons, cross-platform

I am trying to change the icon that appears on my tk application for Mac OS. The last time I checked this code worked for windows. The goal is for this solution to work across all platforms.

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)

app.master.iconbitmap("my_icon.ico")

app.mainloop()
```

The code is adding the default icon for a .pdf file which is not what I intended. The path to the `my_icon.ico` is correct. Why won't this work for Mac OS? Is there an ultimate solution that will work cross-platform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the `tk tcl` documentation you may want to try `wm iconphoto`. It appears it may support OSX and it also mentions to set the file to around a 512x512 for smooth rendering in MAC.

I do not have MAC so I cannot test this but give this a shot and let me know if it helped.

Update:

As @l'L'l pointed out you may want to try `root.iconphoto(True, img)`. I am unable to test it myself due to not having Mac.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
img = tk.Image("photo", file="icon.gif")
# root.iconphoto(True, img) # you may also want to try this.
root.tk.call('wm','iconphoto', root._w, img)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the relevant text from the [documentation here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm):

> wm iconphoto window ?-default? image1 ?image2 ...? Sets the titlebar
>   icon for window based on the named photo images. If -default is
>   specified, this is applied to all future created toplevels as well.
>   The data in the images is taken as a snapshot at the time of
>   invocation. If the images are later changed, this is not reflected to
>   the titlebar icons. Multiple images are accepted to allow different
>   images sizes (e.g., 16x16 and 32x32) to be provided. The window
>   manager may scale provided icons to an appropriate size. On Windows,
>   the images are packed into a Windows icon structure. This will
>   override an ico specified to wm iconbitmap, and vice versa.
>
> On X, the images are arranged into the _NET_WM_ICON X property, which
>   most modern window managers support. A wm iconbitmap may exist
>   simultaneously. It is recommended to use not more than 2 icons,
>   placing the larger icon first.
>
> On Macintosh, the first image called is loaded into an OSX-native icon
>   format, and becomes the application icon in dialogs, the Dock, and
>   other contexts. At the script level the command will accept only the
>   first image passed in the parameters as support for multiple
>   sizes/resolutions on macOS is outside Tk's scope. Developers should
>   use the largest icon they can support (preferably 512 pixels) to
>   ensure smooth rendering on the Mac.

I did test this on windows to make sure it at least works there. I used a blue square image to test.

If the above documentations is accurate it should also work on MAC.

[image]

Comment: `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "icon.ico"` I think the issue lies with with the file type `.ico` and not the method for adding the file to tkinter.

Comment: @Jake I am not using an .ico file. `ico` is only for windows. Linux has its own file type as well. Try a gif file and see how that goes.

Comment: Is there a file type that would work cross platform? I would like to avoid doing something like `if platform == windows: .ico` `if platform == mac: .gif ....`

Comment: @Jake For this kind of method you are not actually using an ICON file. That is why gif works here. So `gif` would or should work on all systems.

Comment: Actually this (ancient) technique doesn't seem to work for `macOS` (which uses `X11` as it's window manager). It's simple enough to change the `title` attribute on such windows, however, on Mac the window always uses the default `X11` icon regardless of having `tkinter` point to an icon. As a side note, instead of calling `tk` for the icon you should just do `root.iconphoto(True, img)`...

Comment: @l'L'l So for x11 is it just not possible (pre-exe) to change the tkinter icon?

Comment: @Mike-SMT So the method you described worked to a certain degree. The icon showed up on the dock and looked fine.  However, there was no icon that showed up in the window near the title. I will try @l'L'l suggestion tonight. Is there a certain extension for an `x11` icon, or just `icon.x11`?

Comment: @Jake I am not sure you can get the Icon to work near the title. I think l'L'l was saying you cannot make macOS do this but the part that shows up on the dock can be managed with this method.

Comment: Yes this is correct; I believe the only way to get a custom icon in the window itself would be to put the script within an .app bundle, which somewhat defeats the purpose of using a single file.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Mac OS you have to use a .icns image instead a .ico image.

you can use:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from platform import system

platformD = system()
if platformD == 'Darwin':

    logo_image = 'images/logo.icns'

elif platformD == 'Windows':

    logo_image = 'images/logo.ico'

else:

    logo_image = 'images/logo.xbm'

root = Tk()
root.title("My App")
root.iconbitmap(logo_image)
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that worked for me, changing the application icon rather than the window icon using the `pyobjc` module.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sys

root = tk.Tk()

if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    try:
        from Cocoa import NSApplication, NSImage
    except ImportError:
        print('Unable to import pyobjc modules')
    else:
        ns_application = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
        logo_ns_image = NSImage.alloc().initByReferencingFile_('/path/to/icon.icns')
        ns_application.setApplicationIconImage_(logo_ns_image)
else:
    pass # handle other platforms

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Also works for other GUI's besides tkinter.  Like pywebview.

Answer (score 1):

**Important Note:** This method is long and a lot of work for the task at hand. However, it does come with some unrelated benefits. Note that there might be a better way, but this will work.

Anyway, moving on....

You can use py2app.

`Py2app` will turn your program into a `.app`, meaning it runs as an application (because it is). When using `tkinter` this is usually what you want in the end because GUIs are usually turned into apps for ease of use. You can read the py2app documentation [here](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or read a non-official but easier to understand (in my opinion) tutorial [here](https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/). I will also sum up how to do the process.

First install `py2app`:
Enter this into the command prompt:

```
sudo pip install -U py2app
```

If successful, you should get `py2app`.
If not, one problem might be you don’t have `pip`. You can download it with another command:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Step one:
Create a file called `setup.py` in the same dictionary 
as the program.

Step two:
Put this into the file.

```
from setuptools import setup

#APP would be the name of the file your code is in.
APP = ['example.py']
DATA_FILES = []
#The Magic is in OPTIONS.
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': False,
    'iconfile': 'app.icns', #change app.icns to the image file name!!!
    }

setup(
    app=APP,
    name='Your app’s name', #change to anything
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Step 3:
Then open the bash terminal in the dictionary the file is in and type this command:

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

The `-A` makes the app respond to updates in the code, but makes the app unsharable. When you are done developing, rerun the command, this time without the `-A`, like so:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

Note: You may need to use the command `python3 setup.py py2...` instead of `python setup.py py2...` for a python 3 py2app.

Step 4:
Navigate to `the dictionary your code is in/dist`. In that folder will be your app. (The `dist` folder should have been created in step three when you ran the command)

For windows users: py2app is not what should be used, instead use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org).

Comment: I don't see how this would solve the original problem of the icon not appearing.

Comment: This will create its own icon, removing the tkinter default. I forgot to specify how to change the `py2app` default image, editing that now...

Comment: Please see edited answer. Sorry I forgot to include image changing. ;) The change is in Step 2, that part with `'iconfile': 'app.icns'`

Comment: This is a solution for a stand alone app. The OP just wants to change the ICON on the top left of the window during execution of code from IDE.

Comment: @Mike - SMT True, but a stand alone app, which most tkinter programs turn into anyway, has its own logo. This **will** create a stand alone app, but it also will solve his problem, which was to set the icon. It may not be the best answer with its side effects, but the side effects are probably helpful anyway. And the answer works just the same.

Comment: Well after some digging I may have found something that will work without converting to EXE. Sadly I do not have the ability to test on Mac first.

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter.iconbitmap` creates a proxy icon on mac which is a shortcut to that file. If you right click a file and select `get info`, the window that popes up has an icon. It is the icon of the file. You can drag the icon, and that will move the file.  That is a proxy icon. If you set the `iconbitmap`, with an `.app` file the proxy icon will be that app. Since files dragged from the applications folder create shortcuts, if the `.app` you set `iconbitmap` to be, it will make a short cut if you drag the icon of the title bar. This is helpful because you don't want the user to be able to just drag your icon file out of it's directory, so it doesn't work next time your tkinter program loads that `.app` file.[image] Before you convert your tkinter program to an app add `root.iconbitmap("/Applications/<appname>.app")`.
Then move your app to the applications folder. When you open your app your tkinter window will have the icon of your app.If you drag the icon into a different folder it will create a short cut to your app.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me for

- macOS Ventura
- Python 3.11.4

The only way that works for me was given by ChatGPT 4

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage


# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Set the window title
root.title("My Application")

# Load the image: png/gif tested
icon = PhotoImage(file='path/to/icon.png')

# Set the window icon
root.iconphoto(True, icon)

# Run the application
root.mainloop()
```