# The icon cannot be shown by using iconbitmap

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.iconbitmap

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Icon')    
root.iconbitmap('Desktop/img.ico')

root.mainloop()
```

[image: here is the result]

I typed the above code. However, the icon is not shown.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set tkinter icon on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826692/set-tkinter-icon-on-mac-os)

Comment: @acw1668  seems that the conclusion is the icon next to the title cannot be shown on Mac os. It only works if the program is turned into a .app file